# JAVA Jetty 9 Websocket SSL

Tags: java, websocket, jetty-9

Does anybody have a clue about how to set up WebSocketContainer with Jetty implementation with SSL but without Hostname Verification? I want to skip the Hostname Verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetty has by default no Hostname Verification.